# Unable to set the Model Attributes after a Backbone model.fetch() call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have come across a lot of examples where the  backbone-view would  be like `var view1  =  Backbone.View.extend( { } )` but unable to get one where the backbone view is returned directly. In the below code I am able to render the default values of the model attribute and display the same in the dust template but when I do `model.fetch()`, in the success function I am able to see the json response in the console but unable to set the fetched values to the model attributes and render the new values. Do, let me know what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

```
 define(function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var $ = require('jquery');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var g = require('global/dust-globals');
    var template = require('text!/dust/table1.dust');

    var SampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
        },

        defaults:{ 
            SampleUpdate:'Test date',
            SampleCount: 0
        },

        urlRoot: "/Sample"
    });

    var obj1 = new SampleModel();

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
           // 'click .search-btn': 'searchBtnClick',
       },

       initialize: function(){
        this.testfunc();
        this.render();
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(g.renderTemplate('TabView', template, {}));
              //template is compiled and rendered successfully
              console.log('CHECK:'+obj1.get("lastUpdate"));
              return this;
          },

          testfunc : function () {
            obj1.fetch({
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    obj1.set("SampleUpdate", response.get("sampleUpdate"));
                    obj1.set("SampleCount", response.get("sampleCount"));
                    console.log('CHECK1:'+obj1.get("SampleUpdate"));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My JS code calling the above code would be as below.

```
    var TabView = require('/SampleTab');

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.tabView = new TabView({el: '#sample-div', model:this.model, appView: this});
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.tabView.$el.show();
            this.tabView.render();
        }
    });
```

Comment: consider rewording your question, it is not clear

Comment: @mikeapr4 i have reworded the question.. hope this helps to understand

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly it is you are trying to do with your code, but it doesn't look like you're using `Backbone.View.extend({ ... })` correctly. From [the documentation for Backbone.View.extend](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend):

> Get started with views by **creating a custom view class**. You'll want to override the render function, specify your declarative events, and perhaps the tagName, className, or id of the View's root element.

*[Emphasis mine.]*

The `Backbone.View.extend` is for creating your own Backbone View classes, not instantiating objects.

If you're looking for more information, I highly recommend that you read through [Addy Osmani's free e-book, *Developing Backbone.js Applications*](https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/). You might know some of what it teaches already, but it has some good examples of extending Backbone Views and does a much better job of explaining other fundamentals of using Backbone.js than I could here.